# Stop program until getting input from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm setting up a game using JPanel that requires the user to input some information before they play. I have methods in my UI class that gets input from the user. First, I get how many sticks the user wants to play with. Then I get the mode the user wants to play. I call ui.run() and then ui.getMode() but they run at the same time because the program doesn't wait for ui.run() to get the user input.

Here's my code:

```
public int run() {
    createButton("Play", 150, 275, 200, 50, true);
    welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome to the game of sticks!");
    welcomeLabel.setBounds(162, 0, 200, 200);

    createLabel("How many sticks are there on the table initially (10-100)? ", 100, 175, true);
    label.setText("How many sticks are there on the table initially (10-100)? ");
    label.setBounds(100, 175, 400, 50);

    textField.setBounds(190, 225, 130, 30);

    frame.add(textField);
    frame.add(welcomeLabel);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setTitle("Game of Sticks");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocation(200, 200);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(!(textField.getText().isEmpty())) {
                    input = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                    if(input >= 10 && input <= 100) {
                        welcomeLabel.setVisible(false);
                        label.setVisible(false);
                        textField.setVisible(false);
                        button.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }          
    });
    return input;
}

public int getMode() {
    createButton("Submit", 150, 320, 200, 50, true);
    optionLabel.setText("Options:");
    optionLabel.setBounds(225, 50, 100, 100);
    optionLabel.setVisible(true);

    option1.setBounds(175, 125, 100, 100);
    option1.setSize(200, 50);
    option1.setVisible(true);

    option2.setBounds(175, 175, 100, 100);
    option2.setSize(200, 50);
    option2.setVisible(true);

    option3.setBounds(175, 225, 100, 100);
    option3.setSize(200, 50);
    option3.setVisible(true);

    optionTextField.setBounds(190, 275, 130, 30);
    optionTextField.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(optionLabel);
    frame.add(option1);
    frame.add(option2);
    frame.add(option3);
    frame.add(optionTextField);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!(textField.getText().isEmpty())) {
                input = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                if(input >= 1 && input <= 3) {
                    optionLabel.setVisible(false);
                    option1.setVisible(false);
                    option2.setVisible(false);
                    option3.setVisible(false);
                    optionTextField.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }          
    });
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Beyond that, I suggest you start by reading a few tutorials about GUI programming. GUI programs dont "wait" in that sense. You rather look at it from the other way: when something happens (like user entering a value in some field), then that *event* triggers other activities, like for example: enabling another panel.

Comment: I just added some code

Comment: Thanks for that, but please first read or re-read the [mre] link that @GhostCat has given you. It helps *immensely* if we can actually run your code. We don't want the entire program, just a small demo program that shows the problem for us, one where you mock some of the non-essential features of your program.

Comment: And for your own benefit, you'll want to get rid of `frame.setLayout(null);` and learn to nest JPanels and use layout managers.

Comment: Shouldn't `getMode()` be called **inside** the ActionListener, *after* you've validated input (within the if-block)? That is essentially what I'm suggesting below.

Comment: Ah, you're using methods that return a value, and that won't work, not with a dynamic event-driven GUI program.

Comment: *First, I get how many sticks the user wants to play with. Then I get the mode the user wants to play.* - use multiple JOptionPane's to get the user information. A JOptionPane waits until the user closes the dialog. See [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

How does the user start the game?  With a button press? If so, in the button's ActionListener, validate the text held by the JTextField, if valid, start the game, if invalid, don't start the game and instead display a JOptionPane with an error message

You should not be trying to return a value from those methods of yours as that code is a hold-over from linear console programs. Swing is a dynamic event-driven GUI library, and so you should instead be responding to events.

e.g,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (!(textField.getText().isEmpty())) {
        input = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
        if (input >= 10 && input <= 100) {
            welcomeLabel.setVisible(false);
            label.setVisible(false);
            textField.setVisible(false);
            button.setVisible(false);

            // use input here where and how it is needed
        }
    }
}
```

Also, rather than set components visible and invisible, better to swap "views" (JPanels) using a CardLayout. [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: @GhostCat: admittedly the question is a bit vague/unclear to me, and so I have posted an (unfortunately) equally general/vague answer. This is one reason that I posted it as a community wiki, but if you have a better understanding of the question, *please* post your own answer. As always, if I think it good, I will happily up-vote it and even delete this one, if it far outshines it (not hard to do, admittedly)

Comment: @GhostCat best would be if the original poster [edited their original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58475611/edit) posting real [mre] code and text that fully clarified his code and his most specific problem